# Gravar sessão com JavaScript usando cookie e um botão

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

Montei um banner, onde eu preciso que quando o usuário entrar no site e clicar no botão GOT IT ele desapareça e quando o usuário entrar novamente no site ou carregar outro link não apareça mais. Desaparecer eu consegui, mas gravar o usuário com cookie não, achei um exemplo (abaixo) mas não entendi a implementação!!!

OBS: Lembrando que nunca expira

**COOKIE**

```
// Create a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

// Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

// Read a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

// EDIT
// Attaching to a button click (jQuery 1.7+) and set cookie
$("#idOfYourButton").on("click", function () {
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
 });

// Attaching to a button click (jQuery < 1.7) and set cookie
$("#idOfYourButton").click(function () {
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gotit">
    <div>
        <p>We use cookies in order to improve your browsing experience on sugarcane.org, not to collect personal information. By continuing to use the site, you agree that it is OK. <a href="https://sugarcane.org/privacy-policy">Read about our privacy policy.</a></p>
        <a href="#" title="GOT IT">GOT IT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gotit A").click(function(){
    $(".gotit").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Vc quer um cookie com data de vencimento pra expirar? Se sim, quanto tempo?

Comment: não está  faltando o plugin jQuery Cookie?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Creio que sim, mas carregar plugin pra uma coisa tão simples que pode ser feita em JS puro acho desnecessário :D

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) que é um tipo de cookie e definir por quantas horas o banner não será exibido ao clicar no link para fechá-lo.

É preciso ocultar o banner no CSS, pois ele será exibido (ou não) na verificação do cookie:

```
.gotit{
   display: none;
}
```

E o código JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // atribui o LS a uma vaviável
   var cookie = localStorage.getItem("banner");

   // verifica o cookie
   criaCookie();

   $(".gotit A").click(function(){
      $(".gotit").fadeToggle("slow");
      criaCookie(true);
   });

   function criaCookie(a){
      // pega a data atual
      var data = new Date();

      // variável para guardar a data atual
      var data_atual = data.valueOf();

      // adiciona 168 horas (7 dias) à data atual
      var data_pos = data.setHours(data.getHours()+168);

      if(a){
         // cria/redefine o LS com a data +168 horas
         localStorage.setItem("banner", data_pos);
      }else if(cookie < data_atual){
         // verifica se o LS é menor do que a data atual
         // ou se o LS for inexistente e mostra o banner
         $(".gotit").show();

      }

   }

});
```

## Caso queira um cookie sem limite de tempo

O localStorage é infinito por padrão, ou seja, uma vez criado, ele só é removido se o usuário removê-lo do navegador ou pelo método `localStorage.removeItem("banner")`.

A opção abaixo é quando clicar em GOT IT, o banner não aparecer mais no navegador onde o cookie foi criado:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // atribui o LS a uma vaviável
   var cookie = localStorage.getItem("banner");

   // verifica o cookie
   criaCookie();

   $(".gotit A").click(function(){
      $(".gotit").fadeToggle("slow");
      criaCookie(true);
   });

   function criaCookie(a){

      if(a){
         // cria o LS
         localStorage.setItem("banner", null);
      }else if(!cookie){
         $(".gotit").show();
      }

   }

});
```

Comment: Vou testar e ver se dá certo, mas só mais uma pergunta, se o cara deleter os cookies da máquina dele aparecer novamente né? Outra coisa, tem tempo infinito, tipo até ele apagar o cookie e entrar novamente na página?

Comment: Sim, se ele deletar vai aparecer novamente. Pode ser infinito sim. Aliás, o localStorage é infinito por padrão, mas vc pode colocar um tempo, como fiz na resposta.

Comment: legal, entãose eu deixa ali vazio é infinito?

Comment: Funcinou, mas só tem um problema tem que ser display:flex e não block tentei colocar .css('display', 'flex') junto com a linha do show mas não funcionou

Comment: Seria sem o show: `$(".gotit").css('display', 'flex') ;`. O .show() é display block.

Comment: vlw agora foi já dei uma up no seu post

Comment: Blz. Agora vc pode marcar ✔ em uma das respostas que resolveu a questão.

Answer (score 3):

**Sem plugin jquery cookie**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (document.cookie.indexOf("the_cookie3=") <=0) {
      $(".gotit").css('display', 'flex') ;
      //$('#gotit').show();
  }

  $(".gotit A").click(function(){
      $(".gotit").fadeToggle("slow");
    
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("the_cookie3=") <= 0) {
           alert("O cookie não existe vou criar");

           var date = new Date();
                
          //expira em 7 dias
          //date.setTime(date.getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));
                
          //expira em 30 segundos para usar como teste
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
                
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = "the_cookie3=the_value"+expires+"; path=/"; 
    
         }
  });
});
```

**HTML** colocar um div

```
<div class="gotit" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Faltou só  a verificação quando abre a página, se vai mostrar ou não o banner.

Comment: vou dar um up no seu post tb pq funcionou mas só faltou o que o Sam disse ai e o tempo infinito

Comment: @Sam, certo, mas tem dificuldade em verificar se o cookie é valido?

Comment: humm... Eu não tenho experiência com esse tipo de cookie :/

Comment: opa, @Sam, eu não entendo onde o banner se encaixa, não há banner em lugar algum. Mas acho que a resposta agora atende o que vc falou no primeiro comentário

Comment: Ainda tá meio miado esse código rs... se já tem uma classe, pq colocar um id na div? E o banner vai aparecer só pra depois ser ocultado? :?/

Comment: @Sam, veja se ainda tá meio miado ou agora ficou meio latido :)

Comment: Agora ficou legal. Só esse `$('#gotit').show();` que não tem razão de existir. Mas ficou legal.

Comment: @Sam esquecimento

Answer (score -1):

Talvez isso lhe ajude.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(){ 
    $.cookie("block", "none",{ expires: 9999999 });
    $(".gotit").css("display", "none");   
}); 
var none = $.cookie("block");
$(".gotit").css("display", none);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div class="gotit">
<div>
    <p>We use cookies in order to improve your browsing experience on sugarcane.org, not to collect personal information. By continuing to use the site, you agree that it is OK. <a href="https://sugarcane.org/privacy-policy">Read about our privacy policy.</a></p>
    <a href="#" title="GOT IT">GOT IT</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode substituir o seguinte trecho $(".gotit").css("display", "none"); que esta dentro do CLICK, por $(".gotit").fadeOut(100); para desaparecer lentamente.